# How to destroy widget in GtK 3 python

Tags: python-2.7, gtk3

I would like to complete the following code in order to destroy window when I click on widget to close window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio
import sys

class MyWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Menubutton Example", application=app)
        self.set_default_size(600, 400)

        grid = Gtk.Grid()

        menubutton = Gtk.MenuButton()
        menubutton.set_size_request(80, 35)
        grid.attach(menubutton, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        menumodel = Gio.Menu()
        menubutton.set_menu_model(menumodel)
        menumodel.append("New", "app.new")
        menumodel.append("Quit", "app.quit")

        self.add(grid)

class MyApplication(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.show_all()

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

        new_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("new", None)
        new_action.connect("activate", self.new_callback)
        self.add_action(new_action)

        quit_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("quit", None)
        quit_action.connect("activate", self.quit_callback)
        self.add_action(quit_action)

    def new_callback(self, action, parameter):
        print("You clicked \"New\"")

    def quit_callback(self, action, parameter):
        print("You clicked \"Quit\"")
        self.quit()

app = MyApplication()
exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

In case any problem code is here
http://learngtk.org/tutorials/python_gtk3_tutorial/html/application.html

When I clicked on the left top of window to destroy it, it's block and after I have the message is : Do you want to force application to leave or expect any answer?

Comment: Could you clarify your issue (and goal) a bit more? Assuming you want to add dialog check here http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Dialog.html#Gtk.Dialog

Comment: If you test the code you could understand what is about. I want destroying widget when I active quit_callback() or when I click on the top window on linux cross symbol to delete widget

Comment: I tested your code and it worked just fine, clicking "Quit" or "X" both resulted in the window closing. Is this what you want or do you want to remove the button (or something else?)?

Comment: strange on my ubuntu 14 it's not closing

Comment: I just noticed that your example is Python 3, so there is a small chance that that is the cause for your trouble as you are on Python 2.7

Comment: Ok in your opinion what is specific in python 3. I don't know the difference between 2.7 and 3 in my example. On the other and I know 2.7 .

Comment: Could you help me to transform in 2.7 ?

Comment: The only thing that gave it away was the header on the link. Are you sure that your GTK3 is installed correctly? (and the right version?)

Comment: I think so. I have different others code running ok. And Version is GtK 3.8.10

Comment: I just tested my tool Pype compared to Drpython. It's ok with Drpython. Now I understand my Pype is bad.  Thank you very very much. by